# Flask deployment with Celery on Azure

Tags: python, azure, celery

I have a flask application which uses Celery to carry out calculations based on user input in the web interface. The application works fine on my local machine. However, I am having difficulty deploying on Azure web app services.

I was wondering if anyone could point me to resources for running celery on Azure? In particular, I am unsure what celery settings are required. For the local machine I have:
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost/0'

I guess I need to understand which values to use on Azure.
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Should not be much different from your local set-up, apart from making sure that all services are in place and ports open.

Here's what I have (not Azure, but another environment, Linux), as example:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab

broker_url = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
result_backend = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'

imports = ('some.module.job', 'someother.module.job',)

task_serializer = 'json'
result_serializer = 'json'
accept_content = ['json']
timezone = 'Europe/London'
enable_utc = True

beat_schedule = {
    'check-every-30-seconds': {
        'task': 'whatever.task',
        'schedule': dt.timedelta(seconds=30),
        'args': ()
    }
}
```